# personalisation show interstitial ads "ironsource" to activity

Tags: kotlin, integration, ads, ironsource

personalisation show interstitial ads "ironsource" to activity

I tried a lot to add the "irounsource" interstitial with this code "IronSource.showInterstitial();" But always there is a problem in the show ads.

I want to customize the ads so that it does not appear every time the activity are clicked, Like Ads counter.

```js
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.multiplewp.setupaccount.GuidModel
import com.multiplewp.setupaccount.R
import com.multiplewp.setupaccount.Sections.*
import com.multiplewp.setupaccount.Util.InterstitialAdListener
import com.multiplewp.setupaccount.Util.InterstitialUtil
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull


class GuidAdapter(
    var context: Context?,
    var arrayList: MutableList<GuidModel>?,
    var activity: Activity?
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    @NotNull
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        @NotNull parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.guid_list_item, parent, false)
        return ViewDetails(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(@NotNull holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") position: Int) {

        if (holder is ViewDetails) {
            val mholder: ViewDetails = holder as ViewDetails

            mholder.id.text = arrayList!![position].number
            mholder.name.text = arrayList!![position].name

            mholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

                interstitialUtil.loadInterstitial(object : InterstitialAdListener {
                    override fun adClose() {
                        when (arrayList!![position].number) {
                            "1" -> activity!!.startActivity(Intent(context, ActivityA::class.java))
                            "2" -> activity!!.startActivity(Intent(context, ActivityB::class.java))
                            "3" -> activity!!.startActivity(Intent(context, ActivityC::class.java))
                            "4" -> activity!!.startActivity(Intent(context, ActivityD::class.java))
                            "5" -> activity!!.startActivity(Intent(context, ActivityE::class.java))
                            "6" -> activity!!.startActivity(Intent(context, ActivityF::class.java))
                        }
                    }
                })


            })


        }


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList!!.size
    }

    class ViewDetails(@NotNull itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var id: TextView
        var name: TextView

        init {
            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView)
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.guidNameTextView)
        }

    }

    class AdsDetails(@NotNull itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var frameLayout: FrameLayout? = null

    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

}
```

Comment: did you find an answer if yes, please answer your own question